# Is it possible to send data with Bluetooth and Wifi direct at the same time?

Tags: android, bluetooth, wifi-direct

My question is if it is possible to send data from one phone
to another at the same time with Bluetooth and Wifi direct.
Example:
I send a photo from a Samsung device to a Xiaomi device with Wifi direct and at the same time, I am starting to send a
video with Bluetooth from the same Samsung device to the same Xiaomi device. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Do you actually have both devices?

Comment: Yes, but one device has problems with Wifi direct, so I can t test it.

Comment: Do you have any other ideas?